# Error when installing Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Hello I recently tried installing grunt-command line interface according to the instructions on their website using the node package manager command

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

It didnt work and I got the following errors

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/couch-login requires request@'~2.9.202' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.30.0
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
➜  ~
```

I'm not sure how i update this dependancy. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. `npm cache clean`
2. `npm install -g npm`   (update npm)
3. reinstall node.js completely (if all fails).

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: strange as I have reinstalled node.js from the package installer and nothing seems to have changed I still get the same errors?